# Where to start openGL ES to create and rotate a cube in an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, 3d, opengl-es

I've done some apps on iPhone using Objevtive-C and Cocos2d, and I'd like to start learning 3D.
My first goal is to make a very simple app that:
- Displays a 3D cube in the center of the screen.
- And move the camera around the cube
I want something very simple: no texture, no background.

Where should I start to be able to do this app? I'm searching for some tutorials or exemples.
Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I created an [OpenGL ES sample application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/CubeExample.zip) that displays a textured cube, and lets you rotate it using touch gestures, as part of the class I teach on iPhone development.  I warn you, though, I didn't quite get the faces right in that example, so it's up to you to correct my mistakes.  The notes from that course, including the lecture on OpenGL ES, are available in VoodooPad format [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/AdvancediPhoneApps.zip).

For a more complex example, you can download the source code to my iPhone / iPad application [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules).

Comment: I ran your sample app in the simulator.  The textures on some of the faces are backwards.  Is this what you mean when you say that you didn't get the faces right?  Or is there something else a noob like me should be aware of?  Thanks!

Comment: @sigjuice - Yes, the texture coordinates are wrong in parts (they need to be indexed differently), so things don't show up right.  I did this over lunch the day of the class, so I didn't have time to debug it, nor have I revisited it since.  I left it as an exercise to my students, and a couple of them managed to fix the textures, so it's not that hard to get right.