# creating a 3d Cube, controlling rotation using touch movement up, down,left, right iPhone, iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, 3d, cube

I'd like to design a 3d cube, each side of the cube can have a different bitmap image (.png) the cube can be rotated using the finger touches (Up, Down, left, right) double clicking with your finger will return an integer value 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 corresponding to the currently showing surface. I'd also be using the pinch touch methods for fold / unfold feature.

Question is I'm not convinced that using open GL is the right choice. I'm not too savvy using it and am thinking is there a more simple way to do this. If there is any tutorial code hanging around it would be extremely helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: When it comes to the cube display and rotation, my answer here to a similar question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2858658/19679

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you check out [ISGL3d](http://isgl3d.com/) and [cocos3d](http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/)