# iOS OpenGL ES - Only draw on request

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es, frame-rate, redraw

I'm using OpenGL ES to write a custom UI framework on iOS. The use case is for an application, as in something that won't be updating on a per-frame basis (such as a game). From what I can see so far, it seems that the default behavior of the GLKViewController is to redraw the screen at a rate of about 30fps. It's typical for UI to only redraw itself when necessary to reduce resource usage, and I'd like to not drain extra battery power by utilizing the GPU while the user isn't doing anything.

I tried only clearing and drawing the screen once as a test, and got a warning from the profiler saying that an uninitialized color buffer was being displayed.

Looking into it, I found this documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/EAGLDrawable_Ref/EAGLDrawable/EAGLDrawable.html

The documentation states that there is a flag, kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, which when set to YES, will allow the backbuffer to retain things drawn to it in the previous frame. However, it also states that it isn't recommended and cause performance and memory issues, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid in the first place.

I plan to try both ways, drawing every frame and not, but I'm curious if anyone has encountered this situation. What would you recommend? Is it not as big a deal as I assume it is to re-draw everything 30 times per frame?

Comment: Do you have to use GLKViewController? It's not that hard to roll your own OpenGL ES hosting view and a view controller that refreshes that only when needed. It's what all of us had to do pre-iOS 5.0.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that was an option (I'm very new to iOS development). I will look into that.

Comment: I link to a couple of sample applications in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2858658/19679), one simpler than the other. Both create their own custom views and view controllers, and updates are handled manually or via an interruptible CADisplayLink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you shouldn't use `GLKViewController`, as its very purpose is to provide a simple animation timer on the main loop.  Instead, your view can be owned by any other subclass of UIViewController (including one of your own creation), and you can rely on the usual `setNeedsDisplay/drawRect` system used by all other UIKit views.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the backbuffer that retains the image, but a separate buffer.  Possibly a separate buffer created specifically for your view.

You can always set `paused` on the `GLKViewController` to pause the rendering loop.

Comment: Didn't know about the paused property, that sounds like a pretty good solution. Will that pause the update loop as well though (GLKViewControllerUpdate)?

Comment: Yes, the `paused` property stops the `GLKViewController` from updating and rendering the `GLKView`. This is perfect if you want to use `setNeedsDisplay` to render based on irregular changes (eg. user input) but then sometimes animate based on the update timer. For example if you drag something then let go and it springs back, you would unpause the controller until the spring animation finished then pause it again until needed.