# Drawing a 3D Cube and rotate it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, 3d, download, cube

I want to draw a 3D cube and rotate it. I found here a project ( [Where to start openGL ES to create and rotate a cube in an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857463/where-to-start-opengl-es-to-create-and-rotate-a-cube-in-an-iphone/2858658#2858658) )  but there are 4 Errors:
/Users/Zyage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CubeExample-

> cpuqdsorzrsxfcckeaidfhlprjed/Build/Intermediates/CubeExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CubeExample.build/Script-BC9587F7117F8CF400BBB1C8.sh: line 4:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool:
>   No such file or directory
>   /Users/Zyage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CubeExample-cpuqdsorzrsxfcckeaidfhlprjed/Build/Intermediates/CubeExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CubeExample.build/Script-BC9587F7117F8CF400BBB1C8.sh: line 5:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool:
>   No such file or directory
>   /Users/Zyage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CubeExample-cpuqdsorzrsxfcckeaidfhlprjed/Build/Intermediates/CubeExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CubeExample.build/Script-BC9587F7117F8CF400BBB1C8.sh: line 7:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool:
>   No such file or directory
>   /Users/Zyage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CubeExample-cpuqdsorzrsxfcckeaidfhlprjed/Build/Intermediates/CubeExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CubeExample.build/Script-BC9587F7117F8CF400BBB1C8.sh: line 8:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool:
>   No such file or directory

Do you know, how I can fix it?

Comment: The error says: there is a missing directory called 'texturetool'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Xcode became a separate app the /Developer folder was removed and things like texturetool were placed within the Xcode app bundle. The new texturetool path is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool
```

You need to go into Build Phases > Run Script and change the first line from:

```
TEXTURE_TOOL=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool
```

To:

```
TEXTURE_TOOL=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool
```