# OpenGL in iOS - where to start

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I would like to develop a very simple application that allows a user to add shapes to a 3D model and view/rotate the model.

Where do i begin? What are the recommended frameworks for iOS?
Are there any good tutorials you can recommend me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857463/where-to-start-opengl-es-to-create-and-rotate-a-cube-in-an-iphone?rq=1

Comment: This does not answer my questions

Comment: Maybe this help you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1

Comment: I see that this article if from 2011 - is GLkit still recommended?

Comment: GLKit hasn't been superseded by anything and is still a great way to get started with OpenGL ES. Once you've mastered the basics you can graduate from GLKBaseEffect to writing your own GLSL shaders, but there's little reason to stop using GLKMath/GLKTextureLoader/GLKView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's document [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) was very useful in my case. Describes the system integration using straightforward code. Also, gives you an overview about "background and multitasking awareness".

Also, there is a [great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial) for understanding the basic stuff by Ray Wenderlich